# Java program terminating after ObjectMapper.writeValue(System.out, responseData) - Jackson Library

Tags: java, json, jackson, terminate

I'm using the Jackson library to create JSON objects, but when I use the mapper.writeValue(System.out, responseData) function, the program terminates. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> responseData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        responseData.put("id", 1);

        try {
            mapper.writeValue(System.out, responseData);
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }.

}
```

After this executes, the console shows {"id":1}, but does not show "done".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is with the Jackson implementation, as ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue calls UtfGenerator.close(), which calls PrintStream.close().

I'd log an issue at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON

To change the default behavior of target being closed you can do the following:

```
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's feature -- by default OutputStream is indeed closed when using high-level ObjectMapper.writeValue() methods. But good explanation of the actual issue.
You can disable that feature (`JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET`) on ObjectMapper, if behavior is not desired: `mapper.disable(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET)`

Comment: Looks like another overloaded version of the disable method would be handy.  Currently, there isn't one that takes a JsonGenerator.Feature.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, there should then be `mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false)` but granted should add convenience methods too if they are missing.

Comment: Yup, `mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);` did the trick.

Comment: I'd log an issue and ask for it to be changed. The caller created the stream, and should therefore own its lifecycle. Horrible API.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce can i ask which jar contains the package `JsonGenerator`

Answer (score -3):

While declaring variable names in your data files/getter files, the first letter should be small.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @JRichardSnape - I disagree. While the first sentence and the signature need to go, the overall message is that the problem stems from variables being case-sensitive. The answer may be wrong, but it still attempts to answer the question.

Comment: @SomethingDark Fair enough - I see your edit.  I guess there is an attempt to answer here - maybe I was a little quick-fingered in the review queue.